# PowerShell UnauthorizedAccessException writing file on network share

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which minifies a directory full of .js files on the webserver. The files belong to me; I created it; I'm logged in as me. I can open and save the files in a text editor or via a batch file. The PowerShell script thinks it's operating as me (`$env:username`), and I'm running it from a PowerShell console that I ran with "Run As Administrator".

The loop looks like this. $files is confirmed to be a collection of file objects representing the files I want.

```
$tool = "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.exe";

foreach($ofile in $files) {
    $outfile = $ofile.DirectoryName + "\" + $ofile.BaseName + ".min.js";

    & $tool $ofile.FullName > $outfile;
}
```

I get the following error on each file:

```
Access to the path '\\webserver\inetpub\whatever\js\validation.min.js' is denied.
At C:\minifyall.ps1:18 char:27
+     & $tool $ofile.FullName > <<<<  $outfile;
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure
```

The file there is the file it ought to be writing to, and get-acl tells me I have Allow FullControl. It can read the non-.min files just fine.

If I change the output directory to the current working directory (on my own machine), the script works as expected:

```
# No prob
$outfile = $ofile.BaseName + ".min.js";
```

Is there something else I need to do to enable this script to write to remote files? Other than rewriting it in Perl (Update: In the end, I rewrote it in Perl and as of February 2020 have had no trouble with it. **This is not an endorsement of Perl**).

Tips on PowerShell coding style are welcome too. My professional experience with PowerShell began approximately an hour after breakfast today.

Answer (score 1):

Try and print all the full paths in order to see there isn't anything funny going on.

Another a reason could be that, since the target files are Javascript, some security system prevents access. Are you running an antivirus?

If all else fails, use [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what exactly is going on on the filesystem.

Comment: Already printed all the full paths. Nothing unexpected there. We do have a bunch of rabid and hostile securityware... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that file ACLs on the remote machine that grant you permission isn't enough. You also need permission to write on the share.  Go to the remote machine, right click the folder, go to the Sharing tab, Advanced Sharing and click the Permissions button.  Check those permissions to make sure you have write privileges.

Comment: The folder properties dialogs on the remote machine don't have a Sharing tab. Remember, anyway, I can save these files in VS or Notepad.

Comment: You can save them through the network share?  BTW check sharing properties on the folder that corresponds to the "inetpub" share.

Comment: Yes, I can save them via the network share. I ended up just writing a batch file with the .js files listed explicitly on the command line, with full network share paths for input and output files. Works fine. The list isn't going to change that often; PowerShell was kind of overkill for the task. Just seemed like an excuse to start learning it. I'm wondering if PS might not have paranoid assumptions about potentially malicious script behavior.

Comment: The per employee network shares where I work disallow writes of files with certain extensions (EXE, DLL, BAT, etc.) I don't know how that's implemented, whether a feature of Windows or some 3rd party product. The error message is not helpful because it looks like a garden variety access denied message, even though you may have permission via ACLs and the share has write permission. I was going to suggest trying to write a file with a different extension (eg .TXT) but the last comment suggests that extensions aren't likely the problem. I'd be very surprised if PS was doing something though.